# How to remove deadlocks in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, deadlock, database-deadlocks

First of all I would like to know what is the actual root cause of deadlocks in SQL Server 2005. Is it because when two processes access the same row in a table?

Anyways, consider two tables `_Table_Now_` and `_Table_History_` where both having the same structure.

Suppose there is one column called `NAME`.

So when one process tries to UPDATE a record with `NAME='BLUE'` in `_Table_Now_`, first, it need to put the present row with `NAME='BLUE'` into `_Table_History_` then update 
`_Table_Now_`, and also delete previously present row from `_Table_History_`.

Deadlock occurs while deleting. I do not understand why?

Please guide me!

Comment: A deadlock typically involves multiple concurrent transactions. You've described one transaction. What are the other transactions involved in the deadlock?

Comment: good practice is to avoid dead locks by providing hints per query such as `with (NOLOCK)` and `with (ROWLOCK)`, to remove the lock you can kill one of the spids with `kill N` where n is the spid id which will allow the other to continue

Comment: Without more info it's going to be hard to help. Here is a link on how to use SQL profiler to analyze deadlocks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deadlock basically mean when process A is dependent on process B  and process B is dependent on process A, so A will just start\continue when B finishes and B will only start\continue when A finishes

what you may be experiencing are table (or row) lock, so SQL locks the row before updating the table to make sure no other process tries to access that row while it is doing the update.

Can you be more specific on how are you doing the insert\update\delete. You shouldnt have deadlocks in this scenario.

FYI, don't use `with (NOLOCK)`. It will yes prevent from locking but it does so by telling  SQL Server to read uncommitted data, and it can end up in data inconsistencies.

Comment: That is my reason of worry. In normal circumstances there should not be any dead lock. Even when i open the new Query window and write a simple select query like SELECT * FROM _Table_History_ where NAME='BLUE' ... When execute this statement some times it shows dead lock.

Comment: can you give more information on how the deadlock is happening

Comment: Ok.I am using sql server 2005. Now in sql server 2005 some connections are runnable, some are sleeping but some are SUSPENDED. When the no of SUSPENDED connections increases then Applications goes down. I executed sp_who2

Comment: I guess I need to be more strong in sql server 2005. How do i learn the internal working of sqlserver 2005? like in the above situation how does select query actually execute? Any study materials.??

Answer (score 0):

Deadlock occurs when Process A is waiting for Process B to release resources and Process B is waiting for Process A to release resources.

If I understand the order of Updates correctly, it is this:
1. Read a row in Table_Now
2. Update a row in Table_History
3. Update a row in Table_Now
4. Delete a row in Table_History.

This could be a risky order if you are using transactions or locks incorrectly.

To avoid deadlocks, for each process you should execute:
1. Begin Transaction (Preferably table lock)
2. Perform all the DB operations
3. Commit the transaction (or Rollback in case any problem occurs while DB update)

This will ensure each process to lock both the tables, perform all the operations and then exit.

If you are already using transactions, what scope and level are you using? If not, introduce transactions. It should solve the problem.

Comment: In described scenario transactions are sure way to create deadlocks :) You can usually avoid them using (updlock) hint in step 1 - read Table_Now.

Comment: The reason i didnt use the above. I would lose the incoming record if anyone of the above does not work. suppose delete is failed .Hence when roll back then all are reverted. inserting into _Table_Now_ is very high priority